# Como somar os elementos de uma matriz para fazer outra? (SOMA DE VIZINHOS)

Tags: c++

Preciso de um programa que some os numeros vizinhos de cada elemento da matriz com uma distancia r informada pelo usuario, e imprima em outra matriz. ex: {{1 2 3}, {4 5 6}, {7 8 9}} r=2 deve somar 1+2+3+4+7 na primeira posição, etc. POREM, nao estou coonseguindo somar e nem determinar que a primeira posição [0][0] nao podem somar a esquerda pois nao tem numero.
o que eu fz até agora (porem só imprime lixo):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define M 5
#define N 7

void somaVizinhanca (int A[][N], int r, int lin, int col)
{
    int p, som=0, vs[M][N], l=0, c=0,l2=0, c2=0;
    p=0;
     for (int i=0;i<lin;i++)
        {
            cout << endl;
            for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
            {

                som = A[i][j];

                while(p<r){

                    l=i+1;
                    c=j+1;
                    l2=i-1;
                    c2=j-1;


                    if (i==0 && j==0){
                            som = som + A[l2][c];

                    } else if (i==0){
                            som = som + A[l][j] + A[l2][c2];

                    } else if (j==0){
                            som = som + A[l][c] + A[i][c2];

                    } else if (i==4){
                            som = som + A[i][c] + A[l2][c2];

                    } else if (j==6){
                            som = som + A[i][c] + A[l2][j];
                    }

                    vs[i][j] = som;
                    p++;
                }
                cout << vs[i][j];
                cout << " ";
                p=0;
                l2=0;
                c2=0;
                l=0;
                c=0;
            }
        }
}

int main ()
{

    int A[M][N], r, lin, col, i, j;

    cout << "Digite r: ";
    cin >> r;

    cout << "Digite a matriz A: " << endl;

        for (i=0;i<M;i++)
        {

            for (j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                cin >> A[i][j];
            }
        }

        lin = i;
        col = j;



        cout << "A matriz Sv com a soma por vizinhanca eh: ";
        somaVizinhanca(A, r, lin, col);



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para obter os vizinhos basta que o valor absoluto da subtração com o índice seja menor que r. Assim obtemos os vizinhos na vertical e horizontal.

Depois passo os vizinhos para um vetor e faço a soma com o valor atual.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define M 5
#define N 7

int soma(int n, vector<int> arr) {
    int soma = n;
    for (int i : arr) {
        soma += i;
    }
    return soma;
}

vector<int> obterVizinhos(int A[M][N], int lin, int col, int r) {
    vector<int> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (lin == i && col == j) {
                continue;
            }
            if (abs(lin - i) < r && abs(col - j) < r) {
                arr.push_back(A[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

void somaVizinhos(int A[M][N], int r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            vector<int> vizinhos = obterVizinhos(A, i, j, r);
            cout << soma(A[i][j], vizinhos);
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[M][N], r, lin, col, i, j;

    cout << "Digite r: ";
    cin >> r;

    cout << "Digite a matriz A: " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "A matriz Sv com a soma por vizinhanca eh: " << endl;
    somaVizinhos(A, r);



    return 0;
}
```